# Plot gain, cover, weight for feature importance of XGBoost model

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, xgboost

I have a XGBoost model `xgboost_model`. To plot the feature importance of this XGBoost model;

```
plot_importance(xgboost_model)
pyplot.show()
```

The plot shows the F score. However, there are importance metrics like the gain, coverage, weight behind the F score.

How do I plot the importance metrics gain, coverage, weight individually?

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass different importance types to `plot_importance`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(14,30))

nfeats = 15
importance_types = ['weight', 'cover', 'gain']

for i, imp_i in enumerate(importance_types):
    plot_importance(xgboost_model, ax=ax[i], max_num_features=nfeats
                    , importance_type=imp_i
                    , xlabel=imp_i)
```

In the example above, you can build a `subplot`with 3 plots inside, each one for the three types supported by `plot_importance`.

I tested this in `jupyter`. Otherwise, you'd call `plt.show()`.